# Trying to use an Instance variable from a void method (java)

Tags: java, methods, void

I'm currently writing a code that asks for a packages dimensions then uses the volume to calculate the shipping costs.  There is another class that I have not included in the post which handles the cost calculation.  I currently at a loss for how to take the input of the inputLength etc. methods and put them into the Package and Package copy methods.  And also why i cant use them in the calcVolume and displayDimensions methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Package {

    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Package() {

        double length = 1.0;
        double width = 1.0;
        double height = 1.0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.printf("Welcome to Colin's Shipping Calculator!%n%n");
        System.out.printf("Enter first package dimensions%n");

        Package volCalc;
        volCalc = new Package();
        volCalc.inputLength();
        volCalc.inputWidth();
        volCalc.inputHeight();

        System.out.printf("Enter second package dimensions%n");

        volCalc.inputLength();
        volCalc.inputWidth();
        volCalc.inputHeight();

        volCalc.displayDimensions();
        volCalc.calcVolume();
        Shipment shipCalc = new Shipment();
        shipCalc.inputPackage();
        shipCalc.inputPackage();
        shipCalc.calculateCost();
        shipCalc.display();



    }

    public Package(double length, double width, double height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }

    public Package(Package copy) {

        Package newPackage = new Package();
        newPackage.length = copy.length;
        newPackage.width = copy.width;
        newPackage.height = copy.height;

    }

    public void inputLength() {
        System.out.printf("Enter Length: ");
        double length = input.nextDouble();


    }

    public void inputWidth() {
        System.out.printf("Enter Width: ");
        double width = input.nextDouble();

    }

    public void inputHeight() {
        System.out.printf("Enter Height: ");
        double height = input.nextDouble();

    }

    public void displayDimensions() {
        System.out.printf(length + " X " + width + " X " + height);

    }

    public double calcVolume() {
        double volume = length*width*height;
        System.out.printf("%nVolume: " + volume);

        return volume;

    }
```

Comment: @khelwood the assignment instructions indicate that all of the methods i have void be void

Comment: Are your input methods supposed to write values to the instance fields of your class?

Comment: @khelwood yes so, the input methods get the values for the dimensions of two packages(package and package copy) then the Shipment class which i have not included calculates the cost to ship the two packages.  The program should also display the volume and the dimensions of each package.

Comment: Your input methods are only assigning values to local variables, not to instance variables. See the answer someone posted for how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing your member variables by declaring them again in the methods. Try removing the 'double' before the variable name in the functions.

Here an example. I also changed every printf statement to either print or println. But I'm not sure how Shipment should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Package {

    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Package() {
        this.length = 1.0;           // Removed 'double'
        this.width = 1.0;
        this.height = 1.0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Colin's Shipping Calculator!\n");
        System.out.println("Enter first package dimensions");

        Package packageA;
        packageA = new Package();
        packageA.inputLength();
        packageA.inputWidth();
        packageA.inputHeight();

        packageA.displayDimensions();
        packageA.calcVolume();

        System.out.println("Enter second package dimensions");
        Package packageB = new Package();           // New Package

        packageB.inputLength();
        packageB.inputWidth();
        packageB.inputHeight();

        packageB.displayDimensions();
        packageB.calcVolume();

        Shipment shipCalc = new Shipment();
        shipCalc.inputPackage();
        shipCalc.inputPackage();
        shipCalc.calculateCost();
        shipCalc.display();
    }

    public Package(double length, double width, double height) {
        this.length = length;   //'this' needed else shadowing occurs
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Package(Package copy) {
        // Package newPackage = new Package(); Not needed
        this.length = copy.length;  // 'this' just for clarification.
        this.width = copy.width;
        this.height = copy.height;
    }

    public void inputLength() {
        System.out.print("Enter Length: ");
        length = input.nextDouble();    // Removed 'double'
    }

    public void inputWidth() {
        System.out.print("Enter Width: ");
        width = input.nextDouble();     // Removed 'double'
    }

    public void inputHeight() {
        System.out.print("Enter Height: ");
        height = input.nextDouble();    // Removed 'double'
    }

    public void displayDimensions() {
        System.out.println(length + " X " + width + " X " + height);
    }

    public double calcVolume() {
        double volume = length * width * height;
        System.out.println("Volume: " + volume);

        return volume;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I fixed it and think I understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, I have a follow up question, how do I store the values from the input methods in the Package and Package copy?

Comment: As I understand, storing the values in the original package works and you want the values in Package copy to be updated as well.You could do that with Objects like Integer, but I don't understand why you need to copy the Package.

Comment: What i want to be able to do is use the volume off Package A and B in The other class I'm writing to calculate their shipping cost.  As far as I now Package and Package copy should take the values of Package A and B respectively